# Android - Handle TextView from setOnEditorActionListener

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to change the value of a TextView (totacost) inside `setOnEditorActionListener` Event attached to EditText (amount) but it does not work.

x is an object, `x.setAmount()` is a method on `x` to change value of `x.totalcost`, I need to set the new value of `x.totalcost` in the textview.

```
amount.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                    actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
                            event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                    x.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString()));

                   totalcost.setText(""+x.totalcost)
                    return true; // consume.
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: is your listener not being fired? or is it related to your "x" object's method not working as expected? if so paste your class code

Comment: yes sir , I checked the object and the method (x.setAmount) using a Toast and it working correctly to change the value of (x.totalcost) . and the listener is fired too .

Comment: i use this code inside getView method of an adapter so, both EditText and textView are elements of the adapter view. it is a menu of sandwiches  and i need the user to enter the number of sandwiches and then the total cost appears to the user, @Gianfranco